# PHP/MYSQLI - BIGINT value change to Negative

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm facing a wired problem!

I've a table called "student" with one cloumn stuID of type BIGINT,
when i try to assign a value for this column like '20122222222',
if i do it manually it working fine! but with my code it changed to negative value
I searched in stackoverflow for Similar Questions, i found an answer to change the bind_param to string like

```
$stmt->bind_param('s',$stuID);
```

I did it and still the same problem

Here's the function

```
public function insertStudent($stuID)
{
    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO student(stuID) VALUES(?)"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$stuID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        die(printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $this->mysqli->error));
    }
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Is the column type BIGINT UNSIGNED?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
  stuID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (stuID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
Here's the table

Comment: Why are you binding a string `bind_param('s',$stuID);`?

Comment: The soultion was to change the bind to double because 

The largest integer supported in this build of PHP. Usually int(2147483647). Available since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5

Source: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert a record. Try this `rand(111,999)` instead. You will get a unique random numbers starting from 111 to 999. [php rand()](http://www.php.net/rand)

Hope it helps.

Comment: The thing is I'm working with student id which already Exist like this.
It a waste of storage if i make another column and name it id and change stuID from BIGINT to VARCHAR or whatever.

Comment: try to echo out the id before going into the database first. so you can figure out what is the error all about. like doing a try catch, examining every line of the code.

Comment: yul757, Yeah i tried, read my comment under my question. i solved the problem.